# How to handle timeout exception in protractor

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor

I'm using protractor to automate my application.

My test result is displaying **0 failures** after **getting timeout error**

My Code

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id('xoxoxoxo'))), 5000).then(function () {
        element(amkailogo).getAttribute('src').then(function (val) {
        if (val.indexOf('Amkai-Company-Logo') > -1) {
        /.../
        } 
        else {
          /.../
         }
         });
        }, function (err) {
         console.log(err.stack);
        });
```

i gave some random text as a locator **xoxoxoxo**, and the error message is

```
**********Error: Waiting for header displayName
Wait timed out after 5000ms
```

But my test result is

```
Finished in 6.115 seconds
1 test, 0 assertions, 0 failures
```

how to make **expected conditions** to catch **timeout error** so that my console should display **1 failure** instead of **0 failure**
[image]

Comment: Are you using any command line reporters?

Answer (score 0):

Your test doesn't fail because it doesn't have an assertion/`expect`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Brine already pointed out, you don't assert anything in your test, you just have a wait that resulted in an error. In other words, 3 things might happen during a test run:

- test passes
- test fails (expectation failed)
- error (this is what happens here)

Your *test fails with an error* - a timeout error thrown by the `browser.wait()`. And it is quite a normal situation when a test did not pass because of the error as opposed to because of the expectation failure. We just usually provide a *meaningful error message* to ease debugging:

```
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.id('xoxoxoxo'))), 5000, "Element did not become present");
element(amkailogo).getAttribute('src').then(function (val) {
    if (val.indexOf('Amkai-Company-Logo') > -1) {
    /.../
    } 
    else {
      /.../
    }
});
```

And we are actually enforcing to have this [message provided](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor/blob/master/docs/rules/missing-wait-message.md) for every `browser.wait()` in the project by using [`eslint-plugin-protractor`](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) plugin to [`ESLint` static code analysis tool](http://eslint.org/).